# How can I see the full command actually run by a build system in SublimeText2?

Tags: sublimetext2, build-system

I'm writing my own [build system](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) in SublimeText2 but it's not working properly. It would be useful to see the full command that is actually being run to be able to see what's wrong. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When first writing new build rules, I often use `"echo" rest of build rule`.  That will not run your command, but it will print it.

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that. Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer, I had forgotten about it!